# Sencha Touch Mocking

Tags: extjs4, mocking, sencha-touch

I'm looking to create mock ajax responses (json) in my Sencha Touch application for the purpose of developing/visualizing the application before the services are built out.

What is the recommended approach on this? Is there any guidance I can follow? I will be building unit tests as well - should the mocking for unit tests be separate or reusable?

Answer (score 1):

There are approaches how to solve this:

1. While I'm also PHP developer, I created a few simple PHP scripts that returned the JSONs for the development of the Sencha app.
2. Another approach may be the use of some API designing service (such as http://apiary.io/) which allows you to design the API and set default responses
3. You can mock it on the Sencha level - I don't know what you usecase is, but I needed just to display some articles, so I could have used just hardcoded data in the Store.

I wouldn't share the mockings with the unit tests. The reason is that for the development, it is better to use more data (to see how to app is going to look like). But for the unit tests, I would use just minimal amount of data necessary.